# MongoDB aggregation filter

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation

I'm trying to select some data from a mongodb collection in python, here are some example data :

```
[{"id":1, "planned_timestamp":1512728425, "executed_timestamp":0, "owner":1, "action_type": "read", "action_params":"book A"},
{"id":2, "planned_timestamp":1512728430, "executed_timestamp":0, "owner":1, "action_type": "read", "action_params":"book B"},
{"id":3, "planned_timestamp":1512728435, "executed_timestamp":0, "owner":2, "action_type": "read", "action_params":"book C"}]
```

I want to select all task that has `"executed_timestamp":0`, `"planned_timestamp"` lower than the timestamp variable and I would like to have the results as follows:

```
[{"owner":1, "tasks": [{"id":1,"planned_timestamp":1512728425,"action_type": "read","action_params":"book A"},{"id":1,"planned_timestamp":1512728430,"action_type": "read","action_params":"book B"}]},
{"owner":2, "tasks": [{"id":3,"planned_timestamp":1512728435,"action_type": "read","action_params":"book C"}]}]
```

My current request with pymongo is :

```
r = db.task_queue.aggregate(
       [
         { "$group" : { "_id" : "$agent_id", "tasks": { "$push": "$$ROOT" } } }
       ]
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `agent_id`?

What you need is `$match`. Try this.

```
timestamp = 1500000000

r = db.task_queue.aggregate(
        [
            {"$match": {"$and": [
                {
                    "executed_timestamp": {"$eq": 0},
                    "planned_timestamp": {"$lte": timestamp}
                }
            ]}},
            {"$group" : { "_id" : "$owner", "tasks": { "$push": "$$ROOT" } } },
            {"$project":
            {
                "_id": 0,
                "owner": "$_id.owner",
                "tasks": 1
            }}
        ]
    )
```

Comment: agent_id is the same that owner

Comment: Ok, did my script help you?